# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams inbound KTable predictable internal state-store topic names

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We're using Kafka Streams with Spring Cloud Stream Functions. We have the typical example application which joins user clicks `kstream` with user regions `ktable`.

We know we can force custom names for internal changelog or repartition topics by using appropiate methods that accept a name for materialized store when defining our topology:

```java
  @Bean
  public BiFunction<KStream<String, Long>, KTable<String, String>, KStream<String, Long>> bifunctionktable() {
    return (userClicksStream, userRegionsTable) -> userClicksStream
        .leftJoin(userRegionsTable,
            (clicks, region) -> new RegionWithClicks(region == null ? "UNKNOWN" : region, clicks),
            Joined.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long(), null, "bifunctionktable-leftjoin"))
        .map((user, regionWithClicks) -> new KeyValue<>(regionWithClicks.getRegion(), regionWithClicks.getClicks()))
        .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()).withName("bifunctionktable-groupbykey"))
        .reduce((firstClicks, secondClicks) -> firstClicks + secondClicks, Materialized.as("bifunctionktable-reduce"))
        .toStream();
  }
```

But for the input KTable we cannot change its state-store internal topic name and we always get this topic name: `myapp-id-user-regions-STATE-STORE-0000000001-changelog`

If we were fully creating our topology by code we do have `builder.table(final String topic, final Materialized<K, V, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materialized)` method, but using functions... Is there any way to customize the internal topic name for the input KTable in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom name for the incoming `KTable` by using the following property:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.bifunctionktable-in-1.consumer.materializedAs: <Your-custom-store-name>
```

This is documented in [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_state_store) of the reference docs.

Comment: Thanks @sobychacko! Sorry I didn't see that in docs. My fault